# how to use dynamic texture in react-babylonjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, 3d, babylonjs

For example apply it on a plane:

```
const ref = useCallback((node) => {
    const myDynamicTexture = new DynamicTexture("fire", 256, scene);

    const dynamicMaterial = node.hostInstance; //node undefined

    dynamicMaterial.diffuseTexture = myDynamicTexture;
    let ctx = myDynamicTexture.getContext();
}, []);

<plane size={20}>
   <standardMaterial
      ref={ref}
      rotate={[new Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 0.5), Math.PI / 3.0, Space.Local]}
   />
</plane>
```

The problem is, that the property hostInstance in the node object is not defined, but needed to draw on the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the hostInstance property at all.
Just import DynamicTexture from babylonjs with

```
import { DynamicTexture } from '@babylonjs/core'
```

Then create an instance and apply it on the node object.

```
const ref = useCallback((node) => {
    const myDynamicTexture = new DynamicTexture("fire", 256, scene);
    let ctx = myDynamicTexture.getContext();
    
    //draw here with the context (ctx)

    //update if necessary
    myDynamicTexture.update();

    node.diffuseTexture = myDynamicTexture;
    node.opacityTexture = myDynamicTexture;
}, []);
```